# How to access MongoDB in rails without using Mongo as the app's DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I want to be able to access data from a mongoDB while still use my sqlite3 as the db for my app. For example, my controller for my db_call model is the following:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'

include Mongo

class DbCallsController < ApplicationController

  @client = MongoClient.new('localhost', 27017)
  @db     = @client['s7TestDB']
  @coll   = @db['apiLog']
...
```

However when doing this, I am faced with a Routing Error: "uninitialized constant MongoClient"

Comment: What version of the mongo gem are you using?

Comment: What about mongo? `mongo` and `mongoid` are two different gems.

Comment: Sorry I am using gem 'mongo', '1.6.0' and am not using any mongroid gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for the `mongo` gem has changed over time. You need:

```
conn = Mongo::Connection.new
```

Check out the docs for 1.6: http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/1.6.0/

If you want to use the syntax you've already got, just make sure you're using `>= 1.8.0`

Answer (score 0):

For mongo gem 2.0 the syntax is

```
client = Mongo::Client.new('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/database')
```